# has_many multiple associations with different names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many

**Ruby 2.1.0/Rails 4.0.2**

I have a Bus model and a Cluster model. They look as follows:

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :left_centroids, class_name: "Centroid"
  has_many :right_centroids, class_name: "Centroid"
end

class Centroid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bus
end
```

Bus also has a method that is basically KMeans Algorithm, so I run it to replace the old `left_centroids` and then to replace the `right_centroids`. Right and Left differ in the value of a given field from the Centroid Model.

I have tried saving those via simple setting: `@bus.left_centroids = centroids_for_algorithms` and also through `update_attributes`. But whenever I save one, say left, right is overwritten with the values of left, and the other way around, which is pointless in the context of my application.

Am I missing something?

UPDATE: After I run the K Means Algorithm (from the ai4r gem, link in comments), I collect the centroids

```
def algorithm(direction)
  clusters = k_means_algorithm_part

  centroids_to_add_to_bus = Centroid.limit 0
  clusters.centroids.each do |centroid|
    cent = Centroid.create(
      :latitude => centroid[0].to_d,
      :longitude => centroid[1].to_d,
      :catch_time => centroid[2],
      :direction => direction,
      :bus_id => bus_id
    )
    centroids_to_add_to_bus.append cent
  end
  bus = Bus.find(bus_id)
  if direction
    bus.right_centroids = centroids_to_add_to_bus
  else
    bus.left_centroids = centroids_to_add_to_bus
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the algorithm you said?

Comment: I'm using the ai4r gem, details of the algorithm can be found here http://ai4r.org/rdoc/index.html. However, I've try the algorithm before and this is the first time I experience this issue. I will update with some custom code (most likely the root of the problem)

Comment: For clusters algorithm: http://ai4r.org/rdoc/classes/Ai4r/Clusterers/KMeans.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you add another column in the centroids table called type. Now you can use this to apply conditions on your associations. Like this

```
 class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :left_centroids, class_name: "Centroid", -> { where type: 'left_centroid' }
   has_many :right_centroids, class_name: "Centroid", -> { where type: 'right_centroid' }
 end
```

Not sure of the syntax, but I think this should help.

Comment: I could, but the Centroids already have a column named 'direction'. I will try with that.

Comment: Yeah. Just use conditions in the association. And do let us know if it helps.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it didn't work. I managed to avoid declaring two fields with the same model though. Thanks for your help.